# Deleting non-local Git Clones

Tags: git, github

I want to remove someone from my Github team, and I would prefer if I could delete their clone of my repository. Is this possible?

Removing them from the team won't delete their local clone

Comment: Is their copy on their computer?  If so, do you want to dispatch a tactical team to destroy that one too?  Sharing with someone else’s computer is forever.

Comment: There's also what they remember and as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_Recall_(1990_film) shows you cannot really delete that.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know it's not possible. Seizing their repository rights would simply prevent them from further pulling/pushing, but you have basically no control of what they have stored locally.

Answer (score 1):

No, a clone of a Git repository is a copy of the bits and bytes. Once they are copied, you don't have control over them any more (just like with any other computer file). There is no *technical* solution, but you can ask your contributor to remove the repository from their computer. If they really do it is up to them.

Answer (score 0):

In short, it's the rules (the contract, laws), not technical solutions, that prevent source code (and other know-how and assets) from being misused after an employee leaves.

---

Please note that this isn't a git-specific problem and it includes:

1. Emails
2. Work related chats
3. Passwords (in files and in their browser history)
4. Copies of the source code not inside repo clones.

Technically you wouldn't be able to delete files from a person's computer (and that's good. Think of being on the other side). However, having the source code is not the same as being able to use it; or sell it: the employment contracts and other laws usually prevent past employees from using company's assets after they leave.